# sorting table using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I am trying to sort the results from mysql table on the webpage table. I have created buttons(ascending and descending) on required columns. It is working fine for the initial group of data. But when I change to other group of data(say different month) it is redirecting to the initial results page and not to the changed month. I have created this using PHP. One of the table headers is:

```
print "  <th>";
    print " Clientprint";
    print "  <form action=\"#\" method=\"POST\"><button type=\"submit\" name=\"client_val\" value=\"ASC\" style=\"border:0; background:transparent\" /><img src=\"up-icon.png\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\"></button>";
    print "  <button type=\"submit\" name=\"client_val\" value=\"DESC\" style=\"border:0; background:transparent\" /><img src=\"down-icon.png\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\"></button></form>";
    print " </th>\n";
```

Comment: Could you show some code you are using?

Comment: I am receiving the value by: if(array_key_exists('client_val',$_POST))
      $sort_num=$_POST['client_val']; and sending the value $sort_num to the database and then ordering according to the received value:if(array_key_exists('client_val',$_POST))
  {
    if($sort_num == 'DESC')
      $query .= " ORDER BY `client` DESC";
    else
      $query .= " ORDER BY `client`";
  }

Comment: I really dont get what you are trying to do. Please explain it better.

Comment: Hi loko, I have created buttons(Ascending and Descending) under every column name and when I click the button it will send the value ASC or DESC to the corresponding column in the table so that I can "Order By" by that particular column. It is working fine for the initial selection. By when I change the selection, it is displaying the data but I am unable to sort the new data. When I click the button under column name it is redirecting me to the initial data page where I was able to sort.